# Libreoffice : Filtering with a list of value

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm looking for a way to filter rows of a column with multiple values with LibreOffice/OpenOffice.

For example, I have these texts cells :

```
A
B
A
D
....
G
G
D
H
I
```

I want to give a list of value (in cells)

```
A
G
D
...
```

to filter my data :

```
A
A
D
G
G
D
```

But with a large number of lines and values to find.

Is it possible easily ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your sheet of data, select the cells to be filtered and use **Data>Filter>Advanced Filter...**.

Then give the list (range of cells) with content to be filtered (your second data example).

Comment: I tried, but I receive the error "This interval does not contains a valid query" after choose the range of cells and click on OK

Comment: To get rid of the error, pl ensure column heading for both the columns is the same.